# How can I use feeds tamper to remove currency ($) sign when importing prices?

Tags: feeds

I have an integer field that I am using for price info (not commerce) and I am importing from a csv. I need to strip out the $ sign and a blank space after. "$ ". How can I do this with feeds tamper?

Comment: Isn't it easier to update the .csv file?

Comment: No, these are automated, periodic imports and we don't have access to the source.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy.  You can use the "Find replace" tamper under "Text", and then user "$" as the search and "$ " as the replace.  If you want to be fancy you can use the "Find replace REGEX" tamper to make sure you only get the leading $.  IIRC, this needs to include the delimiters.  Using "/^\$/" as the search and "$ " as the replace should work (you need the ^ to anchor to the beginning and then escape the $.  Both of these plugins are part of the base feeds_tamper module.

Comment: I did try the find replace before posting but it didn't take. I assumed it was because of the blank space. I will try the regex way.